# if every element of a set has a null set neighborhood then the set is a null set

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

Let $X\subset\mathbb{R}^n$, such that:

For all $x\in X$ there exists an open neighborhood $x\in U$ such that $X\cap U$ is a null set.

**Prove** that $X$ is a null set.

**Important Note**: By "Null Set" I mean a set of measure zero. not to confuse with the empty set.

Comment: Hint: numerable union of Null sets is a null set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every $x\in X$ there is an open ball $U_x$ such that $U_x\cap X$ is null and $x\in U_x$. Notice that we can pick a subset $V_x\subseteq U_x$ such that $V_x$ is an open ball centered at a point with rational coordinates, $V_x$ has rational radius and $V_x$ contains $x$.

Notice that the family $V_x$ also covers $X$, moreover $V_x$ is a countable family, because there is a countable number of balls with rational radius and coordinates with rational points. We number  the family $W_1,W_2,\dots$.

Now notice that $X=X\cap \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^\infty W_i=\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^\infty (X\cap W_i)$.

So $X$ is a countable union of null sets and thus null.